# Is there a distinction between 64 bit and 32 bit regedit?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, windows-registry

This question is asked out of total ignorance and no access to a 64 bit windows machine, but I would like to know whether there is anything special that needs to be taken into account regarding a 64-bit registry and whether there is a regedit64 the way there was a regedit32.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there is a distinction between 64bit and 32bit regedit. There are both 32bit and 64bit keys in the registry. The default 64bit registry editor will show both of these, the 32bit one only the 32bit keys.

- You can only edit 64bit registry keys using the 64bit version.
- You can edit 32bit registry keys in either version
- You cannot have both versions open at the same time.
- WOW64 presents a different view of the registry to 32bit applications.

See [this MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097) for more details.